# Can i set a value for an element of array by directly referring to the name of the element?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have defined an  array of ranges in the following way.

```
Dim ColLen, ColLenArr As Long
Dim Address, arrears, TotalRent, TenType, Contract, Advance, Start, DueDate, HbDate, TenDate, PayedFull, CounterVar As Range
Dim PropArrear, TenArrearPayed, DavArrearPayed, DateArrearPayed, OweDavis, OweLandlord As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim MainTable As Variant
Dim ArrearTable As Variant
Dim FirstCellCol, FirstCellRow, FirstCellRowArr, FirstCellColArr

'Initializations
'Intitialization of reference values
FirstCellRow = Range("Address").Cells(1, 1).Row ' first row of Main Table
FirstCellCol = Range("Address").Cells(1, 1).Column ' firt Column of Main Table
MainTable = Array(Address, arrears, TotalRent, TenType, Contract, Advance, Start, DueDate, HbDate, TenDate, PayedFull)
ArrearTable = Array(PropArrear, TenArrearPayed, DavArrearPayed, DateArrearPayed, OweDavis, OweLandlord)
MainArrayLength = UBound(MainTable) - LBound(MainTable) + 1 'Number of elements in MainTable Array
ArrearArrayLength = UBound(ArrearTable) - LBound(ArrearTable) + 1 ' Number of elements in ArrearTable Array
ColLen = Range("Address").Rows.Count ' length of column in rows.
ColLenArr = Range("PropArrear").Rows.Count
FirstCellRowArr = Range("PropArrear").Row
FirstCellColArr = Range("PropArrear").Column

For r = 0 To MainArrayLength - 1 ' For each element in the Array, assign a range
    Set MainTable(r) = Range(Cells(FirstCellRow, FirstCellCol + r), Cells(ColLen + FirstCellRow - 1, FirstCellCol))
Next

For r = 0 To ArrearArrayLength - 1 ' For each element index in the Array, assign a range variable
    Set ArrearTable(r) = Range(Cells(FirstCellRowArr, FirstCellColArr + r), Cells(ColLenArr + FirstCellRowArr - 1, FirstCellColArr)) ' set a range for each range variable.
Next
```

Can i access the 'arrear' element of `MainTable()` for instance by the following statement?

MainTable("arrear") instead of `MainTable(1)`

Thank you

Comment: A simple method would be to number Constants (e.g. `Const ARREAR = 1`) and use it **without** double quotes: `MainTable(ARREAR)`. BTW you have to write data type to **each** variable with exception of **variant** ones - these don't need an explicit declaration. And use `Option Explicit` in the declaration head of your code modules in any case.

Comment: you need to understand, VBA does not declare variables in groups, you have to add `as integer`, or whatever, each time. Or else it's declared as variant.

Comment: try option explicit too, i think all tour arrays lack some brackets ( " ).

Comment: Also, dictionaries allow using string, or numbers as key. And as item you can use Objects or string, or numbers. For example : `MyDict("Patrick")=41`.
For arrays you could use a function, too, with a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @ Patrick Lepelletier. I've incorporated your suggestions. However, 1) when i declare each range variable separately i get a mismatch error when i try to output the value from a particular cell in a range using: cells(50,50)= MainTable(arrears).cells(1,1+r). I then tried changing my ranges to variants. No error when i refer to the element by name but all of my elements have the range address of the first element (Address).